# Date is giving one values less then selected date

Tags: angularjs, date

I am using Angular JS Material Design Date Time Picker. I am taking date in dd/MM/YYYY format. When I am accessing value of this field it is giving one value less then selected date.

E.g. Instead of 2017/08/31 it is returning 2017/08/30.

```
<div flex-gt-xs>
     <md-datepicker ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{timezone:'+0530'}" ng-model="objGeneralDetails.strDocumentDate" class="smalltext" name="DocumentDate" md-placeholder="Document Date" style="margin-left:-10px;">
     </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the result is in GMT. How do you read selected value?

Comment: i am directly accessing value of ng-model.  e.g - alert(objGeneralDetails.strDocumentDate);

Comment: Javascript, by default, converts date to your browser's time zone when displaying. Are you in GMT+0530 timezone?